# SpringBoot 3 Upload large file efficiently and performantly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, multipart

I am using spring boot 3, java 21 for a rest api.

One of the API will handle file upload. Files can be pretty big, 2~3GB. Reading the [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html), I read that the `MultipartFile` request will always either save the data to memory or save it as a temporary file. Either way does not work. If possible I want a way to directly stream the `MultipartFile` data as it is being uploaded. I have read some SO posts, some of them is using Apache commons fileupload stream. Those posts are pretty old.

I will share two rest controller methods.

```java
@PostMapping("/{fileId}/content")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_write:files')")
public ResponseEntity<String> postFileFileId(@PathVariable Long fileId,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {
    Optional<FileResourceEntity> fileResourceEntityOptional = fileRepository.findByFileIdAndIsTrashFalse(fileId);
    if (!fileResourceEntityOptional.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    try {
        FileResourceEntity fileResourceEntity = fileResourceEntityOptional.get();
        createFoldersAndSaveUploadFile(fileResourceEntity, multipartFile);
        fileRepository.save(fileResourceEntity);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(UPLOAD_FAILED_MESSAGE);
    }
}

@PostMapping(consumes = { "multipart/form-data" })
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SCOPE_write:files')")
public ResponseEntity<String> postFile(
        @RequestPart("filedetail") FileResourceDetail fileResource,
        @RequestPart("content") MultipartFile multipartFile,
        UriComponentsBuilder ubc) {

    FileResourceEntity savedFile = new FileResourceEntity();
    try {
        FileResourceEntity fileData = fileResourceDTOService.convertToEntity(fileResource);
        savedFile = fileRepository.save(fileData);

        if (!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
            createFoldersAndSaveUploadFile(savedFile, multipartFile);
        }

        URI locationOfNewFile = ubc
                .path("/api/v4/files/{fileId}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedFile.getFileId())
                .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(locationOfNewFile).build();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        fileRepository.deleteById(savedFile.getFileId());
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                .body(UPLOAD_FAILED_MESSAGE);
    }
}


private void createFoldersAndSaveUploadFile(FileResourceEntity fileResourceEntity, MultipartFile multipartFile)
        throws IOException {
    String createDate = fileResourceEntity.getCreatedAt().format(DATE_FORMATTER);
    createFolders(Path.of(rootDataFolder, createDate));
    Files.copy(multipartFile.getInputStream(), getFilePath(fileResourceEntity));
}
```

We are running the application as pod in Kubernetes. Files are saved to a PV, which is actually mounted FSX. Right now, after client finishes upload, server takes a long time to save the multipart file to actual file server, then returns response.

Is there any way to directly save/stream uploads to file using Spring Boot?

Comment: Don't use `MultipartFile` if you want to read it streaming as that will always be read into memory. Instead use the `@RequestPart` to either reference an `InputStream` or a `Part` either should work and should resolve lazily. Also make sure to disable fileuploads through `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false` as that will wrap the request and consume the parts.

Comment: Thank you. I will change the question a bit. As you pointed out, I do not have any constraint to use `MultipartFile`.

Comment: Else use Apache Commons File Upload as there is now a version that supports JakartaEE and thus those old posts should still be applicable. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html as well.

Comment: I did not see any example for multipart/form-data with Apache Commons File Upload, where a part is DTO.

Comment: May I kindly ask to provide a sample controller method with using `InputStream` and `Part`?

Comment: Replace `MultipartFile` with either `Part` or `InputStream`. Problem with the inputstream would be that you don't have any contextual information.

Comment: I am using integration test with MockMultipartFile. If I change to Part, how will I change my integration tests?
`MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "fileName.txt", "text/plain", "Hello World".getBytes());

mockMvc.perform(multipart("/api/v4/files/301/content").file(multipartFile).andExpect(status().isNoContent()).andReturn();`

Comment: Well use `part` instead of `MultipartFile`. Just look at the API and its documentation.